# Hyper-V container time sync issue

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I am running ubuntu on top of windows 10, hyper-v. Everything goes fine but if I lock my laptop even for sometime, time inside ubuntu becomes out of sync with windows machine. I tried various ways like "chronyd" sync etc but nothing works. Things return to normal, if I restart hyper-v container; but it is painful as I need to start all work again from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this issue without restarting hyper-v container (ubuntu, in this case). Here are the steps:

1. Open your hyper-v Manager application.
2. select the container which is having time issue.
3. right click on it and select "settings".
4. Select "Integration services" now, this will show "Time synchronization" check box like this

   [image]
5. uncheck that box and click "apply" button. Now again check that "Time synchronization" checkbox and hit "apply" button.
6. Correct time appears inside container.